# Prioritize left join row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am dealing with some mildly screwy data in MySQL (5.5). I have a table that is being used to track both statuses (new, active, inactive, etc.) and "location" changes, where a location is of the format x.0.y, with x and y being positive integers.

I am trying to move the location changes to a separate table, but in order to do so I need to recover the full old location from other records in the table. The full old location is not stored in the location change records, as you can see below:

```
id      status      new_loc     timestamp
--      ------      -------     ---------
5       1 -> 1      1.0.2       2012-05-21 00:00:00
5       new         1.0.1       2012-05-21 00:00:03
5       1 -> 2      2.0.1       2012-05-22 00:00:00
5       2 -> 3      3.0.1       2012-05-23 00:00:00
```

So, when a location change happens, all that is recorded is the full new location and the first piece of the old location (left side of the status message). However, I can look at previous records to find the full old location.

My main problem is the second row there. A "new" status means the object with id 5 was just added to the database. It should always be the first status for any id in the table. However, there are many cases where the "new" record got inserted about three seconds AFTER the initial change record. In this case, it was added with location 1.0.1, then changed to 1.0.2, then to 2.0.1, then 3.0.1. (Edit: Real examples are not this simple or straightforward, but there is always a "path" of locations that a human can fairly easily discern.)

I run into problems trying to write a query that accounts for both row 1 and row 3. I can't just find the most recent record, because they might be out of order. I can't just grab the record with a new_loc that matches my status, because there might be multiple matches.

Here is what I *think* would work:

1. Find the most recent previous location change, if one exists, and use its new_loc.
2. If no previous change exists, find the record with the "new" status for that id and use its new_loc.

I currently have a LEFT JOIN that matches against BOTH these conditions, but I don't know how to say "only join on condition 2 if nothing matched condition 1" or "prefer rows joined on condition 1."

I just can't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I should make clear that id is an object id, clearly not just an index on this table. The primary key is (id, status).

Comment: Are the locations monotonically increasing? If so, you might be able to order by location (or fragments thereof) to determine which location was previous to the present one.

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no rhyme or reason like that, the location strings are arbitrary and changes are random. I only picked those examples because they're easier to follow, while still maintaining the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just confirm that I understand what you're trying to do. In pseudo code, would this do what you are looking for?

```
given
   table A (as in your answer)
   table B (objectid, old, new)
for any `id`
   get all rows
   order rows by `status` column such that 'new' is the first value, and then numerically
   take the location in the first `status` column c and insert it into table B with values id, 'new', (c).location
   for all remaining `status` fields selected: 
       for any field n, insert into table B with values id, (n-1).location, (n).location
```

That should be possible with a stored procedure...but it may be a painful bit of code to write.